# How to handle 'UNIQUE constraint failed' exception in SQLite

Tags: react-native, sqlite, unique-constraint

I'm new to React Native.

In my application I'm using the SQLite database as a local database, (Primary Key is Reference No, This is unique to each record). In some situations, the server will return the same record a few times and want to avoid adding duplicates to the DB.

I want to handle the "UNIQUE constraint failed" exception. I tried a few solutions but they didn't work for me. So how could I handle this. Please help me to resolve this issue.

My code as follows.

```
addNewJobs(jobs: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.initDB().then((db) => {
                db.transaction((tx) => {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LI_New_Retail (' +
                        DBProperties.CONSTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_REFERENCE_NO + ', ' +
                        DBProperties.CONSTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_REQUEST_DETAILS + ', ' +
                        DBProperties.CONSTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_INSPECTION_HISTORY + ', ' +
                        DBProperties.CONSTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_LOCATION_CONFIRMATION + ', ' +
                        DBProperties.CONSTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_DATE_SCHEDULED + ', ' +
                        DBProperties.CONSTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_CHECKLIST + ', ' +
                        DBProperties.CONSTANT_TABLE_JSON_RESPONSE + ', ' +
                        DBProperties.CONSTANT_TABLE_COLUMN_UPLOADED_IMAGE_LIST
                        + ') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                        [jobs.referenceNumber, JSON.stringify(jobs.requestDetailsDTO),
                        JSON.stringify(jobs.inspectionHistoriesDtos), null,
                        JSON.stringify(jobs.dateScheduled),
                        JSON.stringify(jobs.pharmacyLocationChecklistsDTOS),
                        JSON.stringify(jobs), null])

                        .then(([tx, results]) => {
                            resolve(results);
                        })
                        
                }).then((result) => {
                    this.closeDatabase(db);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("An error occured during data insert to db -- " + JSON.stringify(error));
                    this.closeDatabase(db);
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("adding new inspection jobs function error occured !!! -- " + error);
            });
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table-name` instead of `INSERT INTO...` ?

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli, No, I never used it before. Could you able to explain it little-bit.

Comment: If you have unique constraint ... It'll either add new-record, or ignore the whole command, if there's a duplicate-record...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table-name` is the way to go ...

> If a record doesn't duplicate an existing record, then MySQL inserts
> it as usual. If the record is a duplicate, then the IGNORE keyword
> tells MySQL to discard it silently without generating an error.